# how to display a variable in console c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple console game where you take care of yourself by feeding yourself.

```
using System;

namespace Project1
{
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int hunger = 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");

        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Good choice, " + name);

        Console.WriteLine("Press SPACE to continue");

        while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar))
        {
            // do something
            int h = hunger - 2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You are hungry," + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Press F to feed");

        while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F))
        {
            // do something
            int food = hunger;
        }
    }

}
}
```

How  can I display the current hunger after a change is made too it? I want to display the food level so the player knows to feed it and does not accidentally over feed it. By any chance is there a way to go back to a earlier line so I don't need to copy and paste the thing forever and ever? Thanks.

Comment: You need to read about control flow and creating functions / methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this will be very broad to answer properly, so I'm going to leave it pretty abstract. You need to put reusable logic in methods. You need a "game loop" or "input loop". You need to learn about variables and passing them into methods.

You also may want to introduce a `Player` class as opposed to various variables to hold separate values.

Your game loop may look like this:

```
ConsoleKey input = null;
do
{
    var player = DoGameLogic(input, player);
    PrintGameInfo(player);
    input = ReadInput(player);
}
while (input != ConsoleKey.Q)
```

When you got all this in order and you want to make the output look nice, take a look at [Writing string at the same position using Console.Write in C# 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283669/writing-string-at-the-same-position-using-console-write-in-c-sharp-2-0), [Advanced Console IO in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199321/advanced-console-io-in-net).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the position of the cursor with `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.CursorTop` and overwrite previous values.

```
Cursor.Left = 0;
Console.Write("Hunger: {0:0.00}", hunger);
```

EDIT: AS mentioned by "CodeMaster", you can do:

```
Console.Write("Test {0:0.0}".PadRight(20), hunger);
```

To make sure you have overwritten the previous data if it differs in length.

Comment: This really only answers a small portion of the question. When you do this, you need to make sure that when overwriting parts of the screen, you don't leave previously printed text there.

Answer (score 0):

is this something you wanted to achieve:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int MAX_FEED_LEVEL = 3; //configure it as per your need
        const int HIGHEST_HUNGER_LEVEL = 0; //0 indicates the Extreme hunger

        int hunger = MAX_FEED_LEVEL, foodLevel = HIGHEST_HUNGER_LEVEL;
        string name = string.Empty;
        char finalChoice = 'N', feedChoice = 'N';

        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Good choice, {0}!", name);
        Console.WriteLine();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("current hunger level : {0}", hunger);
            if (hunger > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You are hungry, {0}", name);

            Console.Write("Press F to feed : ");
            feedChoice = (char)Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            if (feedChoice == 'F' || feedChoice == 'f')
            {

                if (foodLevel <= MAX_FEED_LEVEL && hunger > HIGHEST_HUNGER_LEVEL)
                {
                    hunger = hunger - 1; //decrementing hunger by 1 units
                    foodLevel += 1; //incrementing food level
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Feeded!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Current Food Level : {0}", foodLevel);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Well Done! {0} you're no more hungry!", name);
                    goto END_OF_PLAY;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("You chose not to feed !");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("want to continue the game ? (Y(YES) N(NO))");

            finalChoice = (char)Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        } while (finalChoice == 'Y' || finalChoice == 'y');
    END_OF_PLAY:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("===GAME OVER===");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```